# Sort using String Date depending on the Comparator?

Tags: java, date, comparator

I have the following class:

```
public class Book implements Cloneable {
    private int ISBN;
    private String title;
    private String publishDate;
    private int pageCount;
}
```

I could sort depending on `Comparator` using the following code:

```
Comparator<Book> titleComparator = new Comparator<Book>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Book o1, Book o2) {
        return o1.title.compareTo(o2.title);
    }
};

Comparator<Book> ISBNComparator = new Comparator<Book>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Book o1, Book o2) {
        return Integer.valueOf(o1.ISBN).compareTo(o2.ISBN);
    }
};

public void sort(final String field, ArrayList<Book> BookList) {
    final Comparator<Book> comparator;

    if (field.equals("title")) {
        comparator = titleComparator;
    } else if (field.equals("ISBN")) {
        comparator = ISBNComparator;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Comparator not found for " + field);
    }

    Collections.sort(BookList, comparator);
}
```

but how can I sort depending on  the String publishDate when the publish date format is "25/12/2015"?

Comment: Could I suggest that you use a more appropriate type to start with? Ideally Java 8's `LocalDate` type... You're trying to represent a date... so why use a string?

Comment: You would be required to parse the date in `java.util.Date()` format and then compare it. Using plain string value would not be correct.

Comment: That's a good example of why a date shouldn't be a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would be required to parse the date in `java.util.Date()` format and then compare it. Try the below sample code:

```
Comparator<Book> dateComparator = new Comparator<Book>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Book o1, Book o2) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date o1PublishDate = null;
        Date o2PublishDate = null;
        try {
            o1PublishDate = formatter.parse(o1.publishDate);
            o2PublishDate = formatter.parse(o2.publishDate);
        } catch (ParseException pe) {
            pe.printStackTrace();
        }

        return o1PublishDate.compareTo(o2PublishDate);

    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are sure that using Date instead of String is not a choise, use this comparator(You can add some caching to avoid parsing strings every time):

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Comparator;

/**
 *
 * @author EBudaqov
 */
public class StringDateComparator implements Comparator<String>{

    private SimpleDateFormat formatter;

    public StringDateComparator(String dateFormat) {
        formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        try {
            return formatter.parse(s1).compareTo(formatter.parse(s2));
        } catch(ParseException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "01/01/2015";
        String s2 = "02/01/2015";

        System.out.println(new StringDateComparator("dd/MM/yyyy").compare(s1, s2));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your `publishDate` should be a `java.util.Date` object if you're using Java7 or try to the new Java 8 Date API if you can. However, the code should be like this:

```
Comparator<Book> titleComparator = new Comparator<Book>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Book o1, Book o2) {
        return o1.title.compareTo(o2.title);
    }
};
Comparator<Book> ISBNComparator = new Comparator<Book>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Book o1, Book o2) {
        return Integer.valueOf(o1.ISBN).compareTo(o2.ISBN);
    }
};
Comparator<Book> PublishComparator = new Comparator<Book>() {

    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    @Override
    public int compare(Book o1, Book o2) {
        Date d1 = format.parse(o1.publishDate);
        Date d2 = format.parse(o2.publishDate);

        return d1.compareTo(d2);
    }
};
public void sort(final String field, ArrayList<Book> BookList) {

    final Comparator<Book> comparator;

    if (field.equals("title")) {
        comparator = titleComparator;
    } else if (field.equals("ISBN")) {
        comparator = ISBNComparator;
    } else if (field.equals("publishDate")) {
        comparator = PublishComparator;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Comparator not found for " + field);
    }
    Collections.sort(BookList, comparator);
}
```